DateTimeFormatter: how to make numeric format with 4 digit year?
DateTimeFormatter: how to make numeric format with 4 digit year?
DateTimeFormatter ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle dateStyle)

FormatStyle: MEDIUM, Jan 12, 1999
             SHORT,  01/12/99

How to make 01/12/1999 (4 digit year)?
Can not use Pattern here since it must be locale sensitive.
